# typescript apollo gql react pass in variables to functional composition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to inject variables into a GQL query in a functional way like this

```
const ALL_PEOPLE_QUERY = gql`
  query All_People_Query {
    allPeople {
      people {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

interface Data {
  allPeople: {
    people: Array<{ id: string; name: string }>;
  };
};

interface Variables {
  first: number;
};

const AllPeopleComponent = <Query<Data, Variables> query={ALL_PEOPLE_QUERY}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => { ... }}
</Query>
```

from [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/)

doing something like this

```
export const AllPeopleComponent = () => (<Query<Data, Variables> query={ALL_PEOPLE_QUERY}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => { ... }}
</Query>
);


ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><AllPeopleComponent/></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('list'));
```

But how do I inject variables into the query in the reactDom call?

Answer (score 0):

So answering this myself

I ended up using [codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) on my schema with this in my `codegen.yml`

```
overwrite: true
schema: "<endpoint>"
documents: "src/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/schemagql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

It's important to note that the documents refers to actual queries, mutations, etc rather than anything in the schema definition.
So for the above, there is a file to match with (this is changed to add a variable)

```
  query All_People_Query( $name: String!) {
    allPeople(name: $name) {
      people {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
```

This will generate all the types you need

and the final bit

```
const AllPeopleComponent = (props: !!GeneratedVariables!!) => {
  const {data, error ,loading} = useQuery<!!GeneratedQuery!!,!!GeneratedVariables!!>(!!GeneratedDocument!!, { variables: { name: props.name } });
  if (loading)
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error || !data) {
    return <div>ERROR</div>;
  }

  return !!some html!!
};

ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><AllPeopleComponent name="value"/></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is untested as its based on the Apollo documentation, but see my [repo](https://github.com/bythepowerof/react-ts-apollo-client-app/tree/b604ec55de77986c5777af42c58574e033e40a5b) where it does work